# Unable to read bytes from specific blocks of MIFARE with SL018

Tags: arduino, nfc, arduino-uno, rfid, mifare

I am trying to read a specific block from a MIFARE card with a SL018 shield using an Arduino Uno. Writing it is no problem, but for a project me and a classmate are working on we need to be able to read an input (even a 0 or 1 would be enough).

Using a library and a code we found online we came to this code:

```
/**
 *  Arduino to SL018/SL030 wiring:
 *  A4/SDA     2     3
 *  A5/SCL     3     4
 *  5V         4     -
 *  GND        5     6
 *  3V3        -     1
 */

#include <Wire.h> 
#include <SL018.h>

byte block = 0x01;

SL018 rfid;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(19200);

  // prompt for tag
  Serial.println("Show me your tag");
}

void loop()
{
  rfid.seekTag();

  while(!rfid.available());

  Serial.print("Block ");
  printHex(block);
  Serial.print(": ");
  printArrayHex(rfid.getBlock(), 16);
  Serial.print("  ");
  printArrayAscii(rfid.getBlock(), 16);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Does anyone know how we could read a specific part of the code in, for example, block 1?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [example code](https://github.com/marcboon/RFIDuino/blob/master/SL018/examples/sl018demo/sl018demo.ino) of the SL018 libary. You can use the userinterface of the code with a serial terminal. If you want to read a tag, the intresting part is `case 'R':` (Read sector) at line 111.

```
action = READ;
// specify what to read
block = 0;
numBlocks = 16;
// tag has to be selected first
rfid.selectTag();
```

After defining your block, you are possible to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you refer to blocks and that you seem to assume that a block consists of 16 bytes in your calls to `printArrayHex()`, I assume that you try to read MIFARE *Classic* cards.

You would first wait for a tag:

```
rfid.seekTag();
while (!rfid.available());
```

You can then authenticate to the sector that you want to read. For instance, to read block number 5 (which is located in sector 1), you would authenticate to sector 1. Assuming this sector has its key A set to the default value (`FF FF FF FF FF FF`) and configured for read access to block 5, you could use:

```
byte TRANSPORT_KEY[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};

// authenticate current sector using key type A and the key TRANSPORT_KEY
rfid.authenticate(1, 0xAA, TRANSPORT_KEY);
```

Finally, you can read the data from block 5:

```
rfid.readBlock(5);
Serial.print("Block 5: ");
printArrayHex(rfid.getBlock(), 16);
Serial.println();
```

Alternatively, if you want to read the whole memory of a MIFARE Classic 1K card (and assuming that all blocks are readable using key A with the TRANSPORT_KEY value), you could use something like this:

```
for (byte sector = 0; sector < 16; ++sector) {
    // authenticate current sector using key type A and the key TRANSPORT_KEY
    rfid.authenticate(sector, 0xAA, TRANSPORT_KEY);
    for (byte block = 0; block < 4; ++block) {
        rfid.readBlock(sector * 4 + block);

        Serial.print("Sector ");
        Serial.print(sector);
        Serial.print(", Block ");
        Serial.print(block);
        Serial.print(": ");
        printArrayHex(rfid.getBlock(), 16);
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```